# display order items layout in email only for admin in magento

Tags: email, magento, layout, admin

Whenever user place a new order in magento email will send. In this email contains order items with prices.

```
 {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

But i need to send email to customer without order items and email to admin with order items.
So how to write condition to display this layout only for admin email.

thanks,
murali.

Answer (score 0):

The order confirm e-mail is just send one time. If you configured your that the admin receives the order confirm e-mails to it's send to admin in CC.

That means that you can#t easily change the content of the e-mail for customer and admin because it's the same e-mail.

To achieve your goal you should write an own module which observes the `place_order_after` event and sends a seprarat e-mail to the admin e-mail-adress in which you show the products. In the standard template you would erase the part with the products.